# Fiscal Period and Entry Date between Ranges

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two Oracle Tables . One - GLP has a Description Column , Fiscal Start and Fiscal End period.

Second table Order - has a column called entry date. I am trying to write a query where it will give me the Description (from Table GLP )of the Entry Date ( from table Order) . Any ideas how I can achieve that. very new to SQL.

Comment: Please see:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question  and add more detail to your question.

Comment: [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understood the question, presuming that all "date" values you mentioned are `DATE` datatype, that would be a **join** with **between**:

```
select o.entry_date, 
       g.description
from glp g join order o on o.entry_date between g.fiscal_start and g.fiscal_end;
```

Comment: Unfortunately they do not have a link in between them . So I am not sure how to proceed . Any help will be awesome.

Comment: What I posted is all help I could give based on info you provided.